# I am trying to fetch calendars of a user using DLL's for Office 365 and getting Server Error in '/API' Application. Runtime Error

Tags: oauth, calendar, office365, azure-active-directory, office365api

I have the access token of user. Please let me know if you need any other information.

I have seen other similar questions but the solutions didn't worked for me.

The error message is :

`Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException:`

Server Error in '/API' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

`at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.OData.ProxyExtensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass38`2.b__36(IAsyncResult r) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.OData.ProxyExtensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.d__3a`2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Office365CalendarProviderBL.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.d.MoveNext()`

Comment: facing similar issue. Waiting for solution.